# how to groupby using start & end time range of one df & find the start loc & end loc of each slot of vehicles from another df using python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have one dataframe: df1:
This are the slots of vehicles:

```
    CompanyID   RegistrationNo  slotStartTime           slotEndTime
1   602         veh1            2020-07-27 21:12:00 2020-07-27 22:12:00
2   602         veh1            2020-07-27 21:30:00 2020-07-27 22:30:00
3   602         veh2            2020-07-28 22:16:00 2020-07-28 23:16:00
```

Another: df2:
From this data I want to find start location of slots and end location of slots

```
    RegistrationNo  GPSTime         Location
0   veh1            2020-07-27 21:12:00 loc1
1   veh1            2020-07-27 21:15:00 loc2
2   veh1            2020-07-27 21:20:00 loc3
3   veh1            2020-07-27 21:30:00 loc4
4   veh1            2020-07-27 21:45:00 loc5
5   veh1            2020-07-27 22:15:00 loc6
6   veh1            2020-07-27 22:29:00 loc7
4   veh2            2020-07-28 21:45:00 loc8
5   veh2            2020-07-28 22:15:00 loc9
6   veh2            2020-07-28 22:29:00 loc10 
7   veh2            2020-07-28 22:50:00 loc11 
7   veh2            2020-07-28 23:16:00 loc12
```

Expected Result:

```
    CompanyID   RegistrationNo  slotStartTime           slotEndTime      slotStartloc slotEndLoc
1   602         veh1            2020-07-27 21:12:00 2020-07-27 22:12:00  loc1         loc5
2   602         veh1            2020-07-27 21:30:00 2020-07-27 22:30:00  loc4         loc7
3   602         veh2            2020-07-28 22:16:00 2020-07-28 23:16:00  loc10        loc12
```

I have tried using group by daterange but I guess bcoz there is an involvement of another df it is not working and throwing errors

Comment: how do you know, whicha rules you are using to assign start time for veh2 as `loc10`? it has `22:16:00` start time, and loc10 GPS is `22:29`

Comment: @sygneto  bcoz that's the 1st value of that slot for veh2

Comment: ok, look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
df=pd.DataFrame({
    'CompanyID':[602,602,202],
    'RegistrationNo':['veh1','veh1','veh2'],
    'slotStartTime':['2020-07-27 21:12:00','2020-07-27 21:30:00',
                     '2020-07-28 22:16:00'],
    'slotEndTime':['2020-07-27 22:12:00','2020-07-27 22:30:00',
                   '2020-07-28 23:16:00']
})
df2=pd.DataFrame({
    'RegistrationNo':['veh1','veh1','veh1','veh1','veh1','veh1','veh1',
                      'veh2','veh2','veh2','veh2','veh2'],
    'GPSTime':['2020-07-27 21:12:00','2020-07-27 21:15:00',
                     '2020-07-27 21:20:00','2020-07-27 21:30:00',
               '2020-07-27 21:45:00','2020-07-27 22:15:00','2020-07-27 22:29:00',
               '2020-07-28 21:45:00','2020-07-28 22:15:00','2020-07-28 22:29:00',
               '2020-07-28 22:50:00','2020-07-28 23:16:00'],
    'location':['loc1','loc2','loc3','loc4','loc5','loc6','loc7','loc8',
                'loc9','loc10','loc11','loc12',]
})

df['slotStartTime']=pd.to_datetime(df['slotStartTime'])
df['slotEndTime']=pd.to_datetime(df['slotEndTime'])
df2['GPSTime']=pd.to_datetime(df2['GPSTime'])

#for each for in df merge df2 to get you time range start-end
#then take first and last row to get start loc and end loc
result=pd.DataFrame()

for index,row in df.iterrows():
    row= pd.DataFrame(row).T
    df_main = pd.merge(row,df2,on='RegistrationNo')
    # print(df_main)
    df_main = df_main[
        (df_main.slotEndTime>df_main.slotStartTime) &
        (df_main.slotStartTime<=df_main.GPSTime)&
        (df_main.GPSTime<=df_main.slotEndTime)
    ].sort_values(by=['slotStartTime','RegistrationNo'])
    df_main['start_loc'] = df_main.iloc[0]['location']
    df_main['end_loc'] = df_main.iloc[-1]['location']
    result = result.append(df_main)
#here you have 'result' DF with locations, now you need to assign them to original DF

df=df.merge(result,on=['slotStartTime','slotEndTime','RegistrationNo','CompanyID'],how='inner').drop_duplicates(
    keep='last',subset=['slotStartTime','slotEndTime','RegistrationNo']
)
del df['location']
print(df)
   CompanyID RegistrationNo       slotStartTime         slotEndTime             GPSTime start_loc end_loc
4        602           veh1 2020-07-27 21:12:00 2020-07-27 22:12:00 2020-07-27 21:45:00      loc1    loc5
8        602           veh1 2020-07-27 21:30:00 2020-07-27 22:30:00 2020-07-27 22:29:00      loc4    loc7
11       202           veh2 2020-07-28 22:16:00 2020-07-28 23:16:00 2020-07-28 23:16:00     loc10   loc12
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def compare(reg, start, end):
    startslot = df2[(df2['RegistrationNo']==reg) & (df2['GPSTime'].between(start, end, inclusive=True))]['location'].iloc[0]
    endslot = df2[(df2['RegistrationNo']==reg) & (df2['GPSTime'].between(start, end, inclusive=True))]['location'].iloc[-1]
    return startslot, endslot

df2.sort_values('GPSTime', ascending=True, inplace=True)
df1[['slotStartloc', 'slotEndloc']] = df1.apply(lambda x: compare(x['RegistrationNo'], x['slotStartTime'], x['slotEndTime']), axis=1, result_type='expand')

df1
    CompanyID   RegistrationNo  slotStartTime           slotEndTime      slotStartloc slotEndLoc
1   602         veh1            2020-07-27 21:12:00 2020-07-27 22:12:00  loc1         loc5
2   602         veh1            2020-07-27 21:30:00 2020-07-27 22:30:00  loc4         loc7
3   602         veh2            2020-07-28 22:16:00 2020-07-28 23:16:00  loc10        loc12
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that uses `iterrows()` and writes into the data frame with `.at[]`:

```
df['start_loc'] = ''
df['end_loc'] = ''

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    start = row.slotStartTime
    end = row.slotEndTime
    reg = row.RegistrationNo
    
    mask = ((df2['RegistrationNo'] == reg) & 
            (start <= df2['GPSTime']) & (df2['GPSTime'] <= end))
    
    df.at[index, 'start_loc'] = df2.loc[mask, 'location'].min()
    df.at[index, 'end_loc']   = df2.loc[mask, 'location'].max()
    
print(df[['start_loc', 'end_loc']])   # other columns omitted to save space

  start_loc end_loc
0      loc1    loc5
1      loc4    loc7
2     loc10   loc12
```